# Find coordinates of intersections

Tags: geometry

I have a coordinate system, shown in black below, in which a point is situated along the $x$-axis. There is a different coordinate system rotated along the $z$-axis by $a$ degrees, shown in red in the figure. I can switch between these two systems by a rotation matrix $R$.

Two lines (in the black coordinate system) have constant $y$-values. These two lines intersect the projections of the $x$-point onto the red coordinate system.

I would like to find these two points $P_1$ and $P_2$, but it is not clear to me how I can do that. Can I get a hint?

[image]

---

$\cos$ or $\sin$ will do, of course...

Answer (score 0):

The slope of the graph will be $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2} - a) = m$. Then, you know point $X$.

We need to find the y-intercept of the line going through point $X$, so we use the point-slope formula.

The point-slope formula: $y - y_1 = m(x-x_1)$.

In our case, we know the y-intercept will be on the y-axis, hence $x_1 = 0$, so we're dealing with: $y - y_1 = mx$ where the slope is given as shown above, with $m$. From there, we also know point $X$ is on the x-axis, so we know $y = 0$, which simplifies our equation further to $-y_1 = mx$.

Once you calculate $y_1$, then you know that the line would be of the form $y = mx+y_1$, for variables $x,y$ that you could plug in for figuring out those last two points, $p_1, p_2$ you're interested in.